# T-SQL query to obtain the no of days an item was at the current price

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

```
Declare @sec_temp table 
(
 sec_no varchar(10),
 amount money,
 price_date date
)

insert @sec_temp
values
    ('123ABC', 25, '2011-01-20'), 
    ('123ABC', 25, '2011-01-19'), 
    ('123ABC', 25, '2011-01-18'), 
    ('123ABC', 20, '2011-01-15'), 
    ('123ABC', 22, '2011-01-13'),
    ('456DEF', 22, '2011-01-13')
```

Problem: To list out the distinct sec_no with the latest price (`amount`) and the number of days it was at the current price. In this case,

Result:

```
sec_no   amount  no_of_days_at_price
123ABC   25      3                   e.g. 01-18 to 01-20
456DEF   22      1                   e.g. 01-13
```

Comment: How do you get 5 days for 123ABC? If it extends to current date, then shouldn't 456DEF be 10 days?

Comment: If it is 20-15 = 5, then should 456DEF be 13-13 = 0?

Comment: Another question on logic, shouldn't the price really start counting from "1-18"? IRL, a price would "stay" at 20 (from 1-15) until changed, right?

Comment: @cyberwiki You are right. It should start counting from "1-18"..error on my part

Comment: no worries. Answer edited to match the updated requirement

Answer (score 2):

```
select
 a.sec_no,
 a.amount,
 min(price_date) as FirstDateAtPrice,
 No_of_days_at_price = COALESCE(DATEDIFF(d, c.price_date, a.price_date),0)
from (
 select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by sec_no order by price_date desc) rn
 from @sec_temp) a
outer apply (
 select top 1 *
 from @sec_temp b
 where a.sec_no=b.sec_no and a.amount <> b.amount
 order by b.price_date desc
 ) c
where a.rn=1
```

The subquery A works out the greatest-1-per-group, which is to say the most recent price record for each sec_no.  The subquery C finds the first prior record that holds a different price for the same sec_no.  The difference in the two dates is the `number of days` sought.  If you need it to be one for no prior date, change the end of the `COALESCE` line to 1 instead of 0.

**EDITED** for clarified question

To start counting from the first date equal to the current rate, use this query instead

```
select
 sec_no,
 amount,
 No_of_days_at_price = 1 + DATEDIFF(d, min(price_date), max(price_date))
from (
    select *,
  ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by sec_no order by price_date desc) rn,
  ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by sec_no, amount order by price_date desc) rn2
    from @sec_temp
) X
WHERE rn=rn2
group by sec_no, amount
```

**AND FINALLY** If the required result is actually the days between

- the first date on which the price is equal to current; and
- today

Then the only part to change is this:

```
 No_of_days_at_price = 1 + DATEDIFF(d, min(price_date), getdate())
```

Comment: Nice approach. This also had a lower query cost than the other solutions so far.

Comment: It's also wrong. The current date isn't necessarily the last date for that item, in the table.

Comment: @Josh - where do you see the current date being used in either of my queries?

Comment: I do not see it in either and that is the problem. The current price is the price effective on the max(date) that is *less than now*. When you put pricing into a database, you put it in to be effective for some future date.

Comment: Add insert @sec_temp values ('456DEF', 23, '2012-01-13') to your test case.

Comment: I see where you're coming from. My take is that these are `logged` (after-event) values, in which case the test case is out of scope, @Josh but OP can clarify if that is not so.

Comment: @cyberwiki Thanks for the query and detailed explanation. I was trying to get "date of last changed price" and "last changed price" as well..was trying to get that from the 1st solution using b.amount, b.sec_no..i wasnt sure how to

Comment: @startEnd - I added `FirstDateAtPrice` to the query

Comment: @cyberwiki I meant the date of the prior price (to current) and the prior price(to current)

Comment: @startEnd - That is very far off from the stated question. I suggest you ask it as a new question rather than muddying the current one with related questions in cmments

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach, first looking up the latest price, and then the last price that was different:

```
select  secs.sec_no
,       latest.amount as price
,       case when previous.price_date is null then 1
             else datediff(day, previous.price_date, latest.price_date) 
        end as days_at_price
from    (
        select  distinct sec_no
        from    @sec_temp
        ) secs
cross apply
        (
        select  top 1 amount
        ,       price_date
        from    @sec_temp 
        where   sec_no = secs.sec_no
        order by
                price_date desc
        ) latest
outer apply
        (
        select  top 1 price_date
        from    @sec_temp 
        where   sec_no = secs.sec_no
                and amount <> latest.amount
        order by
                price_date desc
        ) previous
```

This prints:

```
sec_no  price  days_at_price
123ABC  25,00  5
456DEF  22,00  1
```